# OpenUI5 Resource Bundles - Mapping to multiple locales

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to map resource bundles from one locale to another in OpenUI5? We have bundles localized for Norwegian ("no") and we would like to also use them for 
Norwegian Bokmal ("nb"), so that browsers set to either "no" or "nb" will get the same translations.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  What have you tried?

Comment: not sure what you're asking about but: one i18n_no.properties. one i18n_nb.properties. copy and paste the content of the i18n_no.properties to the i18n_nb.properties?

Comment: We're trying to avoid duplicating the files, since the SDK itself only has "no" bundles and we'd have to copy them over to "nb" bundles with each new SDK. Was hoping for some locale chain configuration that allowed us to use the "no" bundles when in the "nb" locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the Language of the Framework on startup with [`sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Configuration.html#setLanguage):

```js
var configuration = sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration();
if (configuration.getLanguage().startsWith("nb")){
   sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("no");
}
```

But beware that this is a global configuration change that will apply to all apps of the same launchpad session.

An other option would be to supply the bundleLocale option to the [ResourceModel constructor](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel.html#constructor).
If you have a Component for your app you could load and change the manifest to supply the bundleLocale to the ResourceModel if the current language is "nb". You should do that in the beginning of your init()-Method before calling the base [Component.init()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.UIComponent.html#init) implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this.